# What is the overall Big O run time of Kruskal’s algorithm if BFS was used to check whether adding an edge creates a cycle?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, kruskals-algorithm

If Kruskal's algorithm was implemented using BFS to check whether adding an edge with create a cycle, what would the overall Big-O run time of the algorithm be?

Comment: Why would you do that? You know if adding an edge would create a cycle in a constant time. Plug O(BFS) in this place and see yourself.

Comment: @user3910703 I can tell you are taking cse100 with diba miriza

Answer (score 4):

It would be `O(V * E + E * log E)`. Each BFS takes `O(V)` time because there are `V - 1` edges in a tree(or less if the tree is not completely build yet) and it is run for each edge(`V` is the number of vertices, `E` is the number of edges).  So it is `O(V * E)` in total. `E * log E` term comes from sorting the edges.

Comment: You should also add that the BFS shall have to be carried out by taking the source vertex as one of the vertices from the new candidate edge and check whether the other vertex is already reachable from it. This is because the partly constructed MST shall be disconnected in Kruskal's algorithm.